# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Tensor'

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import  Concatenate
import tensorflow as tf

im=cv2.imread(val_path)#image reading
im = np.array(im) # no channel
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # no channel
dx = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0)  # float
dy = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1)

mag = cv2.magnitude(dx, dy)  # gradient magnitude , no channel
mag = np.clip(mag, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)  
mag = cv2.cvtColor(mag, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)  # convert mag to RGBA
mag = np.array(mag)#(282, 366, 3)

concat = Concatenate([im, mag])# using Concatenate of tensorflow.keras.layers
concat = tf.cast( concat, dtype=tf.float32)
#concat:(564, 366, 3)

input_image=np.expand_dims(concat, axis=0)/255.0)# <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
output_image_t, output_image_r = sess.run([transmission_layer, reflection_layer],feed_dict={input: input_image})###error
#transmission_layer, reflection_layer is fine
```

I have to concatenate original color image and graident magnitude image

I got an error that

> output_image_t, output_image_r = sess.run([transmission_layer,
> reflection_layer],feed_dict={input: input_image})#sess.run doesn't
> work with tf.keras.layers.   File
> ""/home/semi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py"",
> line 950, in run
> run_metadata_ptr)   File ""/home/semi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py"",
> line 1142, in _run
> np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)   File ""/home/semi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py"",
> line 83, in asarray
> return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

what is my probelm?

my total code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os,scipy.io
import tensorflow as tf
#import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim  #tf.contrib doesn't exist in TF 2.0. over => only TF 1.14 that is old
import tf_slim as slim#only can be TF 2.0.1, TF 2.1 and TF 2.2.
#TensorFlow-Slim: TensorFlow에서 복잡한 모델을 정의, 교육 및 평가하기 위한 경량 라이브러리
#tensorflow-2.2.0   python3.5-3.8    cudnn7.6 cuda10.1
# slim is VGG에 대해 이미지넷 데이터셋을 기반으로pre-trained된 모델을 기반으로 fine-tuning하는 과정이 단순화
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib # GPU를 잘 사용할 수 있게 확인
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES']=str(0) # Uses GPU
print('**************************************************************************************************************')
tf.test.is_gpu_available(#GPU 사용이 가능하다(True)는 메시지가 떴다면 설치가 성공적으로 된 것
    cuda_only=True, min_cuda_compute_capability=None
)

print(device_lib.list_local_devices())# GPU list output
print('**************************************************************************************************************')
#tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 6631 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)

channel = 64
EPS = 1e-12
vgg_path=scipy.io.loadmat('./VGG_Model/imagenet-vgg-verydeep-19.mat')

# our reflection removal model
# build VGG19 to load pre-trained parameters
def get_weight_bias(vgg_layers,i):
    weights=vgg_layers[i][0][0][2][0][0]
    weights=tf.constant(weights)
    bias=vgg_layers[i][0][0][2][0][1]
    bias=tf.constant(np.reshape(bias,(bias.size)))
    return weights,bias
def conv(batch_input, out_channels, stride):
    with tf.variable_scope("conv"):
        in_channels = batch_input.get_shape()[3]
        filter = tf.get_variable("filter", [4, 4, in_channels, out_channels], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(0, 0.02))
        padded_input = tf.pad(batch_input, [[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0]], mode="CONSTANT")
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(padded_input, filter, [1, stride, stride, 1], padding="VALID")
        return conv
def build_net(ntype,nin,nwb=None,name=None):# 여기가 문제야
    if ntype=='conv':
        return tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(nin,nwb[0],strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME',name=name)+nwb[1])
    elif ntype=='pool':
        return tf.nn.avg_pool(nin,ksize=[1,2,2,1],strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='SAME')
def build_vgg19(input,reuse=False):
    #with tf.variable_scope("vgg19"):
    with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope("vgg19"):
        if reuse:
            tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
        net={}
        vgg_layers=vgg_path['layers'][0]
        net['input']=input-np.array([123.6800, 116.7790, 103.9390]).reshape((1,1,1,3))
        net['conv1_1']=build_net('conv',net['input'],get_weight_bias(vgg_layers,0),name='vgg_conv1_1')
        net['conv1_2']=build_net('conv',net['conv1_1'],get_weight_bias(vgg_layers,2),name='vgg_conv1_2')
        net['pool1']=build_net('pool',net['conv1_2'])
        net['conv2_1']=build_net('conv',net['pool1'],get_weight_bias(vgg_layers,5),name='vgg_conv2_1')
        net['conv2_2']=build_net('conv',net['conv2_1'],get_weight_bias(vgg_layers,7),name='vgg_conv2_2')
        net['pool2']=build_net('pool',net['conv2_2'])
        net['conv3_1']=build_net('conv',net['pool2'],get_weight_bias(vgg_layers,10),name='vgg_conv3_1')
        net['conv3_2']=build_net('conv',net['conv3_1'],get_weight_bias(vgg_layers,12),name='vgg_conv3_2')
        net['conv3_3']=build_net('conv',net['conv3_2'],get_weight_bias(vgg_layers,14),name='vgg_conv3_3')
        net['conv3_4']=build_net('conv',net['conv3_3'],get_weight_bias(vgg_layers,16),name='vgg_conv3_4')
        net['pool3']=build_net('pool',net['conv3_4'])
        net['conv4_1']=build_net('conv',net['pool3'],get_weight_bias(vgg_layers,19),name='vgg_conv4_1')
        net['conv4_2']=build_net('conv',net['conv4_1'],get_weight_bias(vgg_layers,21),name='vgg_conv4_2')
        net['conv4_3']=build_net('conv',net['conv4_2'],get_weight_bias(vgg_layers,23),name='vgg_conv4_3')
        net['conv4_4']=build_net('conv',net['conv4_3'],get_weight_bias(vgg_layers,25),name='vgg_conv4_4')
        net['pool4']=build_net('pool',net['conv4_4'])
        net['conv5_1']=build_net('conv',net['pool4'],get_weight_bias(vgg_layers,28),name='vgg_conv5_1')
        net['conv5_2']=build_net('conv',net['conv5_1'],get_weight_bias(vgg_layers,30),name='vgg_conv5_2')
        return net
def lrelu(x):
    return tf.maximum(x*0.2,x)
def relu(x):
    return tf.maximum(0.0,x)
def nm(x):
    w0=tf.Variable(1.0,name='w0')
    w1=tf.Variable(0.0,name='w1')
    return w0*x+w1*slim.batch_norm(x)
def identity_initializer():
    def _initializer(shape, dtype=tf.float32, partition_info=None):
        array = np.zeros(shape, dtype=float)
        cx, cy = shape[0]//2, shape[1]//2
        for i in range(np.minimum(shape[2],shape[3])):
            array[cx, cy, i, i] = 1
        return tf.constant(array, dtype=dtype)
    return _initializer
def build(input): #TF-Slim으로 VGG-19모델 구현
    print("[i] Hypercolumn ON, building hypercolumn features ... ")
    vgg19_features = build_vgg19(input[:, :, :, 0:3] * 255.0)
    for layer_id in range(1, 6):
        vgg19_f = vgg19_features['conv%d_2' % layer_id]
        input = tf.concat([tf.image.resize(vgg19_f, (tf.shape(input)[1], tf.shape(input)[2])) / 255.0, input],axis=3)
    net = slim.conv2d(input, channel, [1, 1], rate=1, activation_fn=lrelu, normalizer_fn=nm,
                      weights_initializer=identity_initializer(), scope='g_conv0')
    net = slim.conv2d(net, channel, [3, 3], rate=1, activation_fn=lrelu, normalizer_fn=nm,
                      weights_initializer=identity_initializer(), scope='g_conv1')
    net = slim.conv2d(net, channel, [3, 3], rate=2, activation_fn=lrelu, normalizer_fn=nm,
                      weights_initializer=identity_initializer(), scope='g_conv2')
    net = slim.conv2d(net, channel, [3, 3], rate=4, activation_fn=lrelu, normalizer_fn=nm,
                      weights_initializer=identity_initializer(), scope='g_conv3')
    net = slim.conv2d(net, channel, [3, 3], rate=8, activation_fn=lrelu, normalizer_fn=nm,
                      weights_initializer=identity_initializer(), scope='g_conv4')
    net = slim.conv2d(net, channel, [3, 3], rate=16, activation_fn=lrelu, normalizer_fn=nm,
                      weights_initializer=identity_initializer(), scope='g_conv5')
    net = slim.conv2d(net, channel, [3, 3], rate=32, activation_fn=lrelu, normalizer_fn=nm,
                      weights_initializer=identity_initializer(), scope='g_conv6')
    net = slim.conv2d(net, channel, [3, 3], rate=64, activation_fn=lrelu, normalizer_fn=nm,
                      weights_initializer=identity_initializer(), scope='g_conv7')
    net = slim.conv2d(net, channel, [3, 3], rate=1, activation_fn=lrelu, normalizer_fn=nm,
                      weights_initializer=identity_initializer(), scope='g_conv9')
    net = slim.conv2d(net, 3 * 2, [1, 1], rate=1, activation_fn=None,
                      scope='g_conv_last')  # output 6 channels --> 3 for transmission layer and 3 for reflection layer
    return net

def print_hi(name):
    test_path = ["./figures/"]
    subtask="result" # if you want to save different testset separately
    val_names=prepare_data_test(test_path)
    for val_path in val_names:#이미지들 들어있는 파일에서 이미지 경로 하나씩 가져옴
        testind = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(val_path))[0]# os.path.splitext : 확장자만 따로 분류한다.(리스트로 나타낸다) ,0번째가 확장자
        #os.path.basename 파일 이름만 출력
        print('******************************val_path', val_path)
        if not os.path.isfile(val_path):
            continue
        im=cv2.imread(val_path)# figures파일 안에 있는 이미지들 하나씩 읽음 (296, 400, 3)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # no channel
        dx = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0)  # float 형태의 미분값을 저장
        dy = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1)

        mag = cv2.magnitude(dx, dy)  # gradient magnitude , no channel
        mag = np.clip(mag, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)  # 255보다 커질 수 있으므로 saturate 연산

        mag = cv2.cvtColor(mag, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)  # convert mag to RGBA

        #concat = tf.concat([im, mag],0)# 행이 늘어남 (592, 400, 3)
        concat = tf.cast(mag, dtype=tf.float32)
        input_image = np.expand_dims(np.float32(concat), axis=0) / 255.0# <class 'numpy.ndarray'>  # (1, 592, 400, 3)
        # Define input of your network to which you feed your data
        #input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 564, 366, 3))

        # build the model
        network = build(input_image)###############################################################################################################################
        transmission_layer, reflection_layer = tf.split(network, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=3)############################################################################

        output_image_t=transmission_layer
        output_image_r=reflection_layer
        output_image_t=np.minimum(np.maximum(output_image_t,0.0),1.0)*255.0
        output_image_r=np.minimum(np.maximum(output_image_r,0.0),1.0)*255.0
        if not os.path.isdir("./result/%s/%s"%(subtask,testind)):
            os.makedirs("./result/%s/%s"%(subtask,testind))
        cv2.imwrite("./result/%s/%s/input.png"%(subtask,testind),im)
        cv2.imwrite("./result/%s/%s/t_output.png"%(subtask,testind),np.uint8(output_image_t[0,:,:,0:3])) # output transmission layer   ?? output_image_t[batch_size,channel,height, width]
        cv2.imwrite("./result/%s/%s/r_output.png"%(subtask,testind),np.uint8(output_image_r[0,:,:,0:3])) # output reflection layer

def prepare_data_test(test_path):
    input_names=[]
    for dirname in test_path:
        for _, _, fnames in sorted(os.walk(dirname)):
            for fname in fnames:
                if is_image_file(fname):#이미지 확장자에 포함 되면
                    input_names.append(os.path.join(dirname, fname))
    print(input_names)
    return input_names

def is_image_file(filename):
    return any(filename.endswith(extension) for extension in IMG_EXTENSIONS)

IMG_EXTENSIONS = [
    '.jpg', '.JPG', '.jpeg', '.JPEG',
    '.png', '.PNG', '.ppm', '.PPM', '.bmp', '.BMP',
]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('PyCharm')
```

Comment: It's because ```tf.keras.layers.Concatenate``` doesn't accept numpy array. You have to define model with tf.keras.layers and build the model, then feed numpy data.

Comment: i know and i have everything my only problem is "input_image=np.expand_dims(np.float32(concat), axis=0)/255.0)############## error"

Comment: Do you want Tensor or np.array?

Comment: i want to input_image=np.expand_dims(concat, axis=0)/255.0) have no error

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. Is your input_image is tensor, or np.array? If np.array, don't use tf.keras.layers.Conatenate. You can't usually mix up np.array and tf.Tensor

Comment: oh sorry, i want to""" output_image_t, output_image_r = sess.run([transmission_layer, reflection_layer],feed_dict={input: input_image})###error """

Comment: sess.run doesn't work with tf.keras.layers.

Comment: how i need to change...?

Comment: There are many to be changed in your code, so I'm lost how to answer. 1. Define your model 2. Prepare your data 3. run training. You may want to follow https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not on eager mode with tf1.14, you can use tf.placeholder to feed your data.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Prepare input data to your network
im = cv2.imread(val_path)  # image reading
im = np.array(im).astype(np.float32)  # no channel
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # no channel
dx = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0)  # float
dy = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1)

mag = cv2.magnitude(dx, dy)  # gradient magnitude , no channel
mag = np.clip(mag, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)  
mag = cv2.cvtColor(mag, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)  # convert mag to RGBA
mag = np.array(mag).astype(np.float32)  # (282, 366, 3)

concat = np.concatenate([im, mag], axis=0)  # (564, 366, 3)  # tf.keras.layers doesn't work only when eager mode
# concat = tf.cast(concat, dtype=tf.float32)  # can't use tf.cast unless eager mode

input_image = np.expand_dims(concat, axis=0) # (1, 564, 366, 3) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
input_image /= 255.

# Define input of your network to which you feed your data
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 564, 366, 3))

# define your network
transmission_layer = ...
reflection_layer = ...

# Run Graph on GPU/CPU and feed data.
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # input is tensor and input_image is numpy array
    # returned output_image_t and output_image_r is np array
    output_image_t, output_image_r = sess.run(
        [transmission_layer, reflection_layer],
        feed_dict={input: input_image})
    )
```

If you are on eager mode, you can't use `tf.placeholder`, nor `tf.Session`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe

tfe.enable_eager_execution()

# Prepare input data to your network
im = cv2.imread(val_path)  # image reading
im = np.array(im).astype(np.float32)  # no channel
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # no channel
dx = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0)  # float
dy = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1)

mag = cv2.magnitude(dx, dy)  # gradient magnitude , no channel
mag = np.clip(mag, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)  
mag = cv2.cvtColor(mag, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)  # convert mag to RGBA
mag = np.array(mag).astype(np.float32)  # (282, 366, 3)

concat = tf.concatenate([im, mag], axis=0)  # Tensor (564, 366, 3). tf.keras.layers might not work. I recommend you are consstent with tf.Tensor
# concat = tf.cast(concat, dtype=tf.float32) not needed but this would work

input_image = np.expand_dims(concat, axis=0) # (1, 564, 366, 3) <class 'numpy.ndarray'> because of np.expand_dims
input_image /= 255.

# go on your network
transmission_layer = ...
reflection_layer = ...

# Run Graph on GPU/CPU and feed data
print(transmission_layer)
print(reflectionlayer)
```

Comment: my TF is 2.0 i can't use session   how can i convert that `output_image_t, output_image_r=sess.run([transmission_layer, reflection_layer],feed_dict={input:input_image})## input is tensor and input_image is numpy array` to TF2.0

Comment: You said you are using tf1.14 yesterday... You can try ```tf.compat.v1.Session``` https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/Session

Comment: i changed TF2.0 to TF1.4 and 1.4T to2.0 many times

Comment: thanks you for reference i got new error `net = slim.conv2d(input, channel, [1, 1], rate=1, activation_fn=lrelu, normalizer_fn=nm, weights_initializer=identity_initializer(), scope='g_conv0')`   `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable g_conv3/w0 from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/g_conv3/w0)`

Comment: Wait, what is this question about? I wanna be useful for you but you can't put so many different questions into this thread. Maybe you have to publish another question. Otherwise, this comment thread lasts forever.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed your code.
It was just a small mistake. You missed a ()

this is the line a changed

```
concat = Concatenate()([im, mag])
```

instead of

```
concat = Concatenate([im, mag])
```

Here is the whole code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import  Concatenate
import tensorflow as tf

im=cv2.imread('C:\....\\tensorflow.jpg')#image reading
im = np.array(im) # no channel
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # no channel
dx = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0)  # float
dy = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1)

mag = cv2.magnitude(dx, dy)  # gradient magnitude , no channel
mag = np.clip(mag, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)  
mag = cv2.cvtColor(mag, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)  # convert mag to RGBA
mag = np.array(mag)#(282, 366, 3)

concat = Concatenate()([im, mag])# using Concatenate of tensorflow.keras.layers
concat = tf.cast( concat, dtype=tf.float32)
#concat:(564, 366, 3)

input_image=np.expand_dims(concat, axis=0)/255.0
output_image_t, output_image_r = sess.run([transmission_layer, reflection_layer],feed_dict={input: input_image})###error
#transmission_layer, reflection_layer is fine
```

Comment: i think it is unavailable i got new error "    concat = concatenate()([im, mag])
TypeError: concatenate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'
"

Comment: it works for me. You are using different keras/tensorflow version. It works on tf 2.3.0

Comment: my TF version is '1.14.0'
 beacause i have to use import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim that required TF V 1.14 only

Comment: Did it really work? ```output_image_t, output_image_r = sess.run([transmission_layer, reflection_layer],feed_dict={input: input_image})``` throws error becuase ```sess``` is not found. I tested in TF2.4.1, even with "with tf.Session() as sess:```, it throws ```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'```. It will work with ```tf.compat.v1.Session```
 https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.3/api_docs/python/tf  downvote.

Comment: I did not test that. trtansmission_layer and reflection_layer was not provived. The only think that the person complained was about the expand_dims that was throwing an error. That was fixed with with () using tf 2.3.0.

Comment: i have to convert `output_image_t, output_image_r = sess.run([transmission_layer, reflection_layer],feed_dict={input: input_image})` to TF2.0